# Show that $A/B$ is cyclic and determine its order for $A=\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ and $B = \{(5m+7n,2m+4n)\mid m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $A$ be the additive group $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$ and let $B$ be the subgroup $\{(5m+7n,2m+4n)\mid m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. Show that $A/B$ is cyclic and determine its order.

I'm absolutely stuck here. Any push in the right direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly $\mathbb Z=\{5m+7n|m,n\in \mathbb Z\}$, this means that every coset $(x,y)+B$ contains  elements of the form $(0,z)$.

We can thus only work with elements of the form $(0,z)+B$. When are two of these equal?

We have $(0,z_1)+A=(0,z_2)+A\iff (0,z_1-z_2)\in A$ if and only if there is $m$ and $n$ with $5m+7n=0$ and $2m+4n=z_1-z_2$, we have $n=-\frac{5m}{7}$ so $m=7l$ and $n=-5l$, we must now have $14l-20l=z_1-z_2$ which has solution if and only if $z_1-z_2$ is a multiple of $6$.

So the group has order $6$, and it is clearly cyclic, as the cosets can be represented by $(0,0),(0,1),(0,2),\dots,(0,5)$.